# Zoom only works on one element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I've created a graph with multiple area plots using `d3.nest()` that are colored by another function. When I attempted to add [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) zoom functionality, I'm only getting it to work with the first area plot.

Here's a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0OkhuUPvXVuUHDikgcD?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.distance); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.elevation); });

var area2 = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.distance); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.elevation); });

// Map colors to limits
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([-10,-5,0,5,10])
    .range(['#a1d99b','#c7e9c0','#fdd0a2','#fdae6b','#fd8d3c','#e6550d']);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

// Caculate the average gradient of a dataGroup.
function dataGroupGradient(dataGroup) {
    return d3.mean(dataGroup, function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value.gradient);
    });
}

var line_points = [];

d3.csv("first5km_Strade_Bianche.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.distance = +d.distance;
    d.elevation = +d.elevation;
    d.latitude = +d.latitude;
    d.longitude = +d.longitude;
    line_points.push([d.latitude, d.longitude]);
  });

  // Split the data based on "group"
  var dataGroup = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.group;
    })
    .entries(data);

  // To remove white space between dataGroups, append the first element of one
  // dataGroup to the last element of the previous dataGroup.
  dataGroup.forEach(function(group, i) {
    if(i < dataGroup.length - 1) {
      group.values.push(dataGroup[i+1].values[0])
    }
  })

  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.distance; })));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.elevation; }))]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  // Add a line and an area for each dataGroup
  dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i){
      focus.append("path")
          .datum(d.values)
          .attr("class", "area")
          .attr("d", area);
      });

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area2);

  dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i){
    context.append("path")
        .datum(d.values)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area2);
    });

  // Fill the dataGroups with color
  svg.selectAll(".area")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(dataGroupGradient(d)); });

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);
});

function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

function type(d) {
  d.distance = parseDate(d.distance);
  d.elevation = +d.elevation;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Comment: put together a JSFiddle, we can see the problem easier that way :)

Comment: I put together a Plunk

Comment: @Will Did this also solve the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202900/d3-zooming-not-working) you posted yesterday regarding zoom functionality?

Comment: No. That one is a different story. It's not zooming at all. I need to add a demo o the question so I can get some help with it. Thanks for asking.

Comment: That's weird. To me your [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0OkhuUPvXVuUHDikgcD?p=preview) shows the same behaviour including zoom along x axis as the [Bl.ock example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) you linked to in your question.

Comment: Yep, that one is working now. This other question you linked in your comment is still looking crazy. The problem is detailed in the question, along with plunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small mistake inside the brush handler:

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);// <-- HERE!
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

The call to `focus.select(".area")` only selects a single path. You want all paths. So, instead, use `selectAll()`:

```
focus.selectAll(".area").attr("d", area);
```

[Updated Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wAH1sNYyGPGr4oYGQVrE?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I knew it was something small.